# Completeness of order statistics for normal setup

Tags: self-study, inference, order-statistics, sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics

Suppose we have iid $X_1,\cdots, X_n\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ where $\mu$ is unknown.

Let $X_{(1)}, X_{(2)},\cdots,X_{(n)}$be the order statistics.

Is the order statistics $\textbf{complete sufficient}$ when

$A)$ $\sigma$ is known ?

$B)$ $\sigma$ is unknown ?

Comment: @whuber I corrected my tag.. Can you please help? At least give a direction of thinking why true or why not true..

Comment: Do you know what the minimal sufficient statistics are for these two cases?  That would be a good place to begin.

Comment: @whuber For first case $\bar{X}$ , and for the second case, $(\bar{X}, \sum(X_i-\bar{X})^2$ . but my concern is about the order statistics.. I know these are sufficient , but not minimal sufficient (for the second case at least)... But i have no clue what to do about completeness

Comment: For completeness, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(statistics)#Example_2:_Sum_of_normals.  For both situations, notice that you can compute the mean and the variance from the order statistics.

Comment: @whuber So you are saying the order statistics are $\textbf{complete}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

I will give a more extended hint, which should cover cases A) and B) simultaneously.  To show that a sufficient statistic is not complete, we need to find a function of it with expectation identically zero.  To this end let the usual sufficient and complete statistic be
$$
   (\bar{X}_n, S_n^2) = \left(\frac1n \sum_1^n X_{(i)},\frac1{n-1}\sum_1^n (X_{(i)}-\bar{X}_n)^2 \right)
$$
which also shows that this sufficient statistic can we written as a function of the order statistics.

Now consider the centered order statistics, given by
$$
( U_1=X_{(1)}-\bar{X}_n, \dotsc, U_n=X_{(n)}-\bar{X}_n )
$$
Can you show that the expectation of $\sum_1^n U_i$ is zero? And what is then the conclusion about the completeness or not of the normal order statistics?