# Proving Order Statistics are Minimal Sufficient

Tags: order-statistics, sufficient-statistics

I am given continuous i.i.d. random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$ having an unknown p.d.f. $f$ and am trying to show that the vector  of order statistics $(X_{(1)}, \dots, X_{(n)})$ is minimal sufficient for the density function $f$. I have shown sufficiency, but am unsure of how to proceed with the minimality.

I have only seen the definition of minimal sufficiency for parameters, but am assuming that this definition carries over to the case of unknown density functions.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/300412/completeness-of-order-statistics-for-normal-setup/324231#324231  (related)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen The link sent seems to show that $(X_{(1)}, \dots X_{(n)})$ is not complete. How does that help to deduce minimality?

Comment: There is a proof in example 4.3.4 around page 118 (nonparametric completeness) of "Testing Statistical Hypothesis (third edition)" by E.L. Lehmann and Joseph P. Romano.  See also https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177705808